# How to open a list of maps installed in device?

Tags: android, dictionary

I want to open a list of installed maps and navigation applications on the device, with a  button click. How do I get the list of **installed map applications such as: yahoo map, google map, bing maps, etc**.
For example, i have AT&T map, Google map, Google navigation and yahoo map on my mobile. Now when user clicks on the button, i just want to open a list which contains all.

Comment: is it just me or is anyone else confused as to what she is talking about?

Comment: Generally, the code for this type of functionality looks like `Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("*/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Provider");` however I don't know an Intent for map apps

Comment: Thanks, my problem is same, i don't know the intent for maps, that's i am looking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass an empty geo-URI to the intent chooser:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, "geo:0,0?q=");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select application"));
```

If you want to get information about activities that support geo-URIs, you can use the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, "geo:0,0?q=");
List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent,
    PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply,But this will open only maps, along with i need the navigation also

Comment: Have you tried "google.navigation:q=" URI to search for navigation activities?

Comment: According to the internet, not every navigation application responds to this URI, so you have to check for known navigation apps.

Comment: That's true, But how to combine both in a single list?

Comment: As far as I know the only way to add additional entries to the intent chooser's list is to pass them in the `Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS` extra. I've never tried this extra but according to the documentation these entries will be added to the beginning of the list. If you need another behavior then you should implement your own intent chooser. That's not so difficult considering that the sources are open.